# How can I "order by" only the LIMIT results in a mysql Query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I need to get the results and apply the `order by` only in the limited section. You know, when you apply order by you are ordering all the rows, what I want is to sort only the limited section, here is an example:

```
// all rows
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY name

// partial 40 rows ordered "globally"
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY name LIMIT 200,40
```

The solution is:

```
// partial 40 rows ordered "locally"
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 200,40) AS T ORDER BY name
```

This solution works well but there is a problem: I'm working with a Listview component that needs the TOTAL rows count in the table (using `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`). If I use this solution I cannot get this total count, I will get the limited section count (40).

I hope you will give me solution based on the query, for example something like: "`ORDER BY LOCALLY`"

Comment: so you only want rows 1-40 sorted?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 200,40` will result in **UNDETERMINED** results. How can that work? What is your expected output?

Comment: why "UNDETERMINED", 200 is the offset, 40 is the count, it works

Comment: Simple answer. If `SELECT * FROM users` comes in an undetermined order then a slice of that result is undetermined :) The `limit` clause will filter the amount... but without an order... which ones are you selecting? Still... for some reason you haven't explained what your expected output is...

Comment: but is determined when you are in the page (200,40) in the listview ........................... may be I need to use Javascript for this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using PHP, might as well make things simple, right? It *is* possible to do this in MySQL only, but why complicate things? (Also, placing less load on the MySQL server is always a good idea)

```
$result = db_query_function("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM `users` LIMIT 200,40");
$users = array();
while($row = db_fetch_function($result)) $users[] = $row;

usort($users,function($a,$b) {return strnatcasecmp($a['name'],$b['name']);});

$totalcount = db_fetch_function(db_query_function("SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS `count`"));
$totalcount = $totalcount['count'];
```

Note that I used made-up function names, to show that this is library-agnostic ;) Sub in your chosen functions.